# Changing physics engine through URDF

Tags: physics

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everybody

Would you please tell me that how can I change physics engine (eg. ODE, Bullet , ...) through launch file and URDF. I have created a package that contains one xacro file (which is used to model and inverted pendulum) and two launch file  that are as follow:

///////////////// Inverted_pendulum_world.launch ////////////////

```
<launch>

  <!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>

  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Load the URDF into the ROS Parameter Server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find ip_cloned)/urdf/inverted_pendulum.xacro'" />


  <!-- Run a python script to the send a service call to gazebo_ros to spawn a URDF robot -->
   <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
    args="-urdf -model inverted_pendulum -param robot_description"/>


</launch>
```

////////////////////Inverted_pendulum_gazebo_control.launch /////////////////

```
<launch>
  <!-- Launch Gazebo  -->
  <include file="$(find ip_cloned)/launch/inverted_pendulum_world.launch" />   


  <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find ip_cloned)/config/inverted_pendulum_gazebo_control.yaml" command="load"/>


  <!-- load the controllers -->
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
    output="screen" ns="/inverted_pendulum" args="joint_state_controller
                      joint1_position_controller"/>


  <!-- convert joint states to TF transforms for rviz, etc -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="/joint_states" to="/inverted_pendulum/joint_states" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

I'm using gazebo 2.2 + Ubuntu 14.04 + ROS Indigo

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14384/changing-physics-engine-through-urdf/) by [Masoud](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2595/masoud/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The easiest thing is to change the .world file you are launching. There you can specify the physics engine and the maximum_step_size. You can add the following code to your world file if you want to speed up simulation to the maximum:

```
<physics type='ode'>
  <max_step_size>0.01</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>0</real_time_update_rate>
  <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
</physics>
```

---

Originally posted by [nzlz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2816/nzlz/) with karma: 90 on 2016-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Whyamihere](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6919/whyamihere/) on 2018-10-30**:
Does this work? has anyone tried?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

URDF does not have the ability to change the physics engine. URDF can represent a single model, but it has no concept of simulation.

You will need to use [SDF](http://sdformat.org) to change the physics engine.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-09-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can specify your physics engine in empty_world.launch: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/jade-devel/gazebo_ros/launch/empty_world.launch#L10

You can do this by adding `<arg name="physics" value="your_preferred_physics_engine" />` in Inverted_pendulum_world.launch, like so:

```
  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="physics" value="your_preferred_physics_engine" />  <!-- this line added -->
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  </include>
```

If that isn't sufficient, or you need to do more detailed tailoring of the physics, you could make a copy of empty.world (in which physics properties are specified), and pass that into empty_world.launch instead.

---

Originally posted by [JLiviero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2765/jliviero/) with karma: 94 on 2016-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Masoud](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2595/masoud/) on 2016-09-25**:
Thank you JLivero...
I'm also wondering if there is a similar way to change maximum_step_size through editing empty_world.lanuch ?

**Comment by [maksymczech](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6341/maksymczech/) on 2020-12-17**:
Thank you, very helpful